# How to stop F1 in VS2010 causing IE9 to stop working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

If Internet Explorer 9 **isn't** running, hitting F1 in Visual Studio 2010 launches it and immediately results in "Internet Explorer has stopped working". If IE9 is already running, hitting F1 opens a new tab and shows the help page. Have you experienced this issue, did you fix it and if so, how?

Comment: try to disable add-ons on IE, run VS in safe mode, reboot the computer, pray, reformat the computer, etc...

Comment: Have disabled all add-ons, running in safe mode, rebooted and prayed. That just leaves reformatting :(

Comment: you can try with another user on the same computer, to see if it's profile related issue, or computer issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required a re-install of Windows 7.